# Pandas dataframe has column title, yet doesn't find the applied filter

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with column titles printed below:

```
Index(['Unnamed: 0', 'material', 'step', 'zaid', 'mass(gm)', 'activity(Ci)',
       'spec.act(Ci/gm)', 'atomden(a/b-cm)', 'atom_frac', 'mass_frac'],
      dtype='object')
```

If I try to obtain data for only, say step 16, and I perform the command:

```
print (df[(16 in df['step'] == 16)])
```

Things work as expected:

```
           Unnamed: 0  material  step   zaid      mass(gm)  activity(Ci)  spec.act(Ci/gm)  atomden(a/b-cm)     atom_frac     mass_frac
    447           447         1    16  90232  2.034000e-09  2.231000e-16     1.097000e-07     9.311000e-12  2.597000e-10  3.048000e-10
    448           448         1    16  92233  2.451000e-08  2.362000e-10     9.636000e-03     1.117000e-10  3.116000e-09  3.672000e-09
    449           449         1    16  92234  4.525000e-05  2.813000e-07     6.217000e-03     2.053000e-07  5.728000e-06  6.780000e-06
    450           450         1    16  92235  1.640000e-01  3.544000e-07     2.161000e-06     7.408000e-04  2.067000e-02  2.457000e-02
    451           451         1    16  92236  1.553000e-02  1.004000e-06     6.467000e-05     6.987000e-05  1.949000e-03  2.327000e-03
    ...           ...       ...   ...    ...           ...           ...              ...              ...           ...           ...
    37781       37781        10    16  67165  5.941000e-05  0.000000e+00     0.000000e+00     1.195000e-08  3.311000e-07  2.785000e-07
    37782       37782        10    16  68166  4.205000e-05  0.000000e+00     0.000000e+00     8.411000e-09  2.330000e-07  1.971000e-07
    37783       37783        10    16  68167  1.804000e-05  0.000000e+00     0.000000e+00     3.586000e-09  9.934000e-08  8.457000e-08
    37784       37784        10    16  68168  7.046000e-06  0.000000e+00     0.000000e+00     1.393000e-09  3.857000e-08  3.303000e-08
    37785       37785        10    16  68170  7.317000e-07  0.000000e+00     0.000000e+00     1.429000e-10  3.958000e-09  3.430000e-09
```

However if I now want to grab data for just the zaid 92235 (which clearly exists as it is displayed in the step 16 results above), according to the command:

```
print (df[(92235 in df['zaid'] == 92235)])
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jack/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 2890, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(key)
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 107, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 131, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1607, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1614, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: False

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "get_pincell_isos.py", line 57, in <module>
    print (df[(92235 in df['zaid'] == 92235)])
  File "/Users/jack/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2975, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
  File "/Users/jack/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 2892, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 107, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 131, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1607, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1614, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: False
```

It apparently can't find "92235", even though I know it exists (shown above) and the data is stored as an int64, the same type as the values in "step".  This is illustrated by printing all values from "step" and "zaid".

```
print (df['step'])
print (df['zaid'])
```

gives the following results:

```
0         0
1         0
2         0
3         0
4         0
         ..
37781    16
37782    16
37783    16
37784    16
37785    16
Name: step, Length: 37786, dtype: int64
0        90230
1        90231
2        90232
3        90233
4        90234
         ...  
37781    67165
37782    68166
37783    68167
37784    68168
37785    68170
Name: zaid, Length: 37786, dtype: int64
```

I hope I'm missing something obvious.  I've tried any number of ways to try to cross-section the 'zaid' column data and no attempts have been successful at recognizing any of the values associated with 'zaid'.

Thanks!

Comment: `df[(92235 in df['zaid'] == 92235)]` should be just `df[df['zaid'] == 92235]`. I'm not sure why it works for 16

Comment: `df[(16 in df['step'] == 16)]`  is not proper syntax.. I suspect you really want `df[df['step'] ==  16]`  or use query `df.query('step == 16')`.

Answer (score 1):

Try `df[df['zaid'] == 92235]`. Try the below code in any ipython console

```
import pandas as pd

data=data = {'state': ['Ohio', 'Ohio', 'Ohio', 'Nevada', 'Nevada', 'Nevada'],
             'year': [2000, 2001, 2002, 2001, 2002, 2003],
             'pop': [1.5, 1.7, 3.6, 2.4, 2.9, 3.2]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['state'] == 'Nevada'
df[df['state'] == 'Nevada']
```